# How to add 2 or more conditions like Excel 2003 in Excel 2010

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting, multiple-conditions

dear,

the problem is I want to make some cells in a column (not a whole column) red,

if its number is greater than or queal to 80,
and
if its number is less than 90.

red if *>=80 and <90* (not *>=80 and <=90*, this can work under the *between* condition in 2010)

in excel 2003, I can add 2 conditions, *>=80*, *<90*, and make them *and* relation in conditional formatting.

how to make it work like 2003 in 2010?

Answer (score 1):

Use `AND()` function.

```
=AND(B2>=80,B2<90)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Highlight the column (or range) you want the format to apply to
2. Conditional Formatting
3. New Rule
4. Use the below setup
5. [image]